# Can we use Union inside generics typehinting in python?

Tags: python, union, type-hinting, mypy

I am writing a function which parses a Union type object with list of parsers (with concrete types) and return a unioned type. However I found I cannot get Union working correctly with List generic.

```
from typing import List,Union,TypeVar
T=TypeVar("T")
T1=TypeVar("T1")

def union_list(l: List[Union[T,T1]] )-> Union[T,T1]:
    return l[0]

test=[0,"_"]
result=union_list(test)
reveal_type(result)
```

I am expecting to get Union[int,str] as a type for result, but got object instead. Is there a way to union listed types without explicitly stating those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you didn't specify `test`'s type. The following will work:

```
from typing import List, TypeVar, Union

T = TypeVar("T")
T1 = TypeVar("T1")


def union_list(l: List[Union[T, T1]])-> Union[T, T1]:
    return l[0]


# Here, specify the type of test
test = [0, "_"]  # type: List[Union[int, str]]
result = union_list(test)
reveal_type(result)
# Happily answers: Revealed type is 'Union[builtins.int, builtins.str]'
```

If you don't specify `test`'s type, mypy will infer that `test`'s type is `List[object]`. If you had given:

```
test = [0, 1]
```

(even without type declaration), mypy would infer that `test`'s type is `List[int]`, and the revealed type of `result` would be `int`.

Comment: So, there's no way to get an auto-typed `List[Union[T,T1]]`. It is a minor disappointment. Either I need to go for a fixed-length Tuple, or disable mypy for all the calls of function. Thank you.

Comment: @Ariksu: it's not quite clear what you really want to achieve here. Can you give a precise (and concise) use case so that we can help you? `:)`.

Comment: @Ariksu -- I don't think your issue has much to do with your `union_list` function. That function's types are fine -- the issue is more that your list has an imprecisely-inferred type. Once you fix that, everything works fine. 
One other note: mypy assumes your lists contain values of the same type, which is why it looks for a common base class instead of inferring a union. So, if your actual list contains some custom classes, I'd try and make them all inherit from the same base class. But if the items in your list really are unrelated, I'd use tuples or something instead, like you suggested.